# OnGetRowsValue returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I have GridView with data which works perfectly fine and everything loads correctly. I need to extract data from one column using button but the function will always return `undefined` even it's loaded correctly.

In same .cshtml file with grid and button I have this "simple" script with 2 functions:

```
<script id="dxss_1610925110" type="text/javascript">
    function ShowValue() {
        gridViewINS.GetRowValues(gridViewINS.GetFocusedRowIndex(), "Insolvency.FileNumber", gridViewINSOnGetRowValues());
    }

    function gridViewINSOnGetRowValues(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

Now when I click the button two alerts pop up. One is `undefined`. The second is literally snippet of my code [which has the value in it which I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBV8f.png). So it can get somehow the data but why not directly to `value` property? I can't find what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the parentheses () from gridViewINSOnGetRowValues().

Like so:

```
gridViewINS.GetRowValues(gridViewINS.GetFocusedRowIndex(), "Insolvency.FileNumber", gridViewINSOnGetRowValues);
```

Comment: Thanks the undefined window stopped. The second window with a weird values still persists though :/

Comment: What you get back in "value" is not the value as a string but a JSON-Object. You need to access the value with its index like value[0][0]. Just put a breakpoint in the gridViewINSOnGetRowValues function and inspect the value object in the debugger.